# How to force inline-block elements to wrap?

Tags: css, backbone.js

I have an inline-block div.

```
.element {
display: inline-block;
}
```

I use jquery to repeatedly append it to the DOM.

```
  var element = $("<div class='element'>");
  $(body).append(element).append(element).append(element).append(element);
```

However the appended divs do not wrap.  It is as if I had the following mark-up (no newlines)

```
<div class="element"></div><div class="element"></div><div class="element"></div><div class="element"></div>
```

Appending whitespace inbetween the elements does not fix problem:

```
  $(body).append(element).append(" ");
```

How can I force these elements to wrap?  (I do not want to use floats).

Comment: Why not just turn your elements into blocks (or leave them like that actually, as that is the default for a div). Inline-block is rarely a good idea... Perhaps you should try to show what you are trying to achieve, or even set up a small fiddle (no need for the js there, just use your output, this is clearly a css issue)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If they are simply `div` elements set to `inline-block` they should wrap like so: http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/

Check and be sure their container/parent element does not have a `white-space:nowrap`. That would cause them to not wrap.

Comment: By default chrome does not wrap inline-block elements, use ```white-space:pre-wrap```

Comment: This is what I want but i want the divs to be centered in the parent div, what should i add?

Comment: This is not the answer because inline-blocks width less than 50% do no wrap

Answer (score 2):

You can give the elements width in terms of percentage. Change the percentage value with regard to the number of elements and how you want to wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend styling the element class with css to create the whitespace. If you don't want to do this you can always try to append a non-breaking space.

```
var element = $("<div class='element' />&nbsp;");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that.  .element:after { content : "\a" } does not work with inline block

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if the ::before pseudo element isn't being used, you can utilize it's powers to solve this issue.

```
element:before { /* single : to support older browsers */
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

this is a solution for **inline** elements