# App Grid like Iphone / Android for web application

Tags: javascript, css, html, open-source

I'm wanting to implement a "Iphone / Andriod" like home screen with various apps into a webpage like this:
 [image]

(By the way it's ERPNext's front page)

Does anyone have any examples that I can build off of? I've tried to use cards however when they scale to mobile there in a single row which does not work for me if I have like 30 smaller app icons inside the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a collection of divs that have been set to display as inline-block, here's an older answer with a JSFiddle that simulates what you're trying to achieve.

[How to force inline-block elements to wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487610/how-to-force-inline-block-elements-to-wrap)

The rest is just aesthetics and simple CSS.

EDIT:
As of 2017 flexbox is the now standard way to go for achieving this goal.